# Proof of Green's Relation

Tags: semigroups

Can anyone tell me where I can get the proofs for the following Green's relations?

1. $a\mathcal{L}b$ iff $\operatorname{Im}(a) = \operatorname{Im}(b)$,
2. $a\mathcal{R}b$ iff $\operatorname{ker}(a) = \operatorname{ker}(b)$,
3. $a\mathcal{D}b$ iff $\operatorname{rank}(a) = \operatorname{rank}(b)$,

where $a,b$ are transformations in $\mathcal{T}_3$.

Comment: What are your thoughts/attempts so far? The more information you can give us, the better we can tailor our answers to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are working in the semigroup $\cal{T}_n$ of all transformations on $\{1, ..., n\}$. Note that the results you mention only hold for regular $\cal D$-classes if you are working in a **subsemigroup** of $\cal{T}_n$. That being said, a good reference for your question is the book

G. Lallement, Semigroups and combinatorial applications, Wiley, 1979

Comment: Yes, its for semigroup T_n. I see this question in most of the books. However, I can't find the solution anywhere or do it myself. If anyone can tell me where I can find the solution for these proof, it will be really appreciated.